# How to kill an individual thread under a process in linux?

Tags: linux, kill, thread

[image]

These are the individual threads of Packet Receiver process. Is there any way to kill any individual thread? Does Linux provide any specific command which can kill or send stop signal to any particular thread under a process?

Comment: What is your Packet Reciever program? (I don't have it on my Debian desktop) Please tell more, perhaps provide some link. So **edit your question** to improve.

Comment: I think you don't realize that the "stop" signal stops a process, regardless of what thread you send it to.

Comment: [Attach with GDB and kill the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8780830/can-gdb-kill-a-specific-thread), then detach.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch Its a program which receives packet from internet and show various URL with user and other information. What I need is to terminate any specific thread under a process for some testing purpose. 

@ David Schwartz Can you please give a small brief on how those kill signals work in stopping any particular thread under any particular process?

Comment: No, I can't. As we all answered, it makes no sense to kill or stop a *single* thread. Actually it looks like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You need to debug your program, and you should explain more.

Comment: @Md.Kawsaruzzaman That just won't work. Suppose, for example, the thread is in the middle of allocating memory and holds the lock on the memory allocator. If you stop the thread, then it will never release the lock and eventually the other threads will stop too. Whatever it is you are trying to do, this is not the way to do it. (It may be that you want to stop the work that thread is doing from being done. But you need the cooperation of the process to do that. If it provides no way to do it, it can't be done.)

Comment: Also note that, in your screenshot, every "thread" has a separate PID. I'm not sure you could even target separate threads, as signals could be sent to processes only.

Answer (score 16):

It generally is pretty dangerous to kill an individual thread from a larger process. That thread might:

- Be modifying some shared state with other threads that could become corrupted
- Be holding some lock which never gets freed, causing the lock to become indefinitely unavailable
- ...or any number of other things which might cause other threads to go wrong.

In general, outside of management and synchronisation by the application itself, killing individual threads is not something that makes sense to do.

Comment: This is not useful at all. OP is asking for _how_ to kill a thread, not whether they should or not.

Comment: What i want is the process to kill or stop any particular thread for some purpose. I assume that due to some  error, sometimes our receiver are getting automatically shutted down. We are finding the causes as the program is developed by our own R&D. Now the thing is there can be a possibility that some threads are automatically getting shutted down. We have tested from code side and got that child thread are independent but from server side still getting some threads down sometimes which causing total process to shut down also..

Answer (score 14):

You might use [tgkill(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/tgkill.2.html) or `tkill` in your C program (you'll need to use [syscall(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html)) but **you don't want to**. From inside your program you can use [pthread_kill(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_kill.3.html) - which is rarely useful.

<sup>(I don't exactly know what effect would have `tgkill` or `tkill` - e.g. with `SIGKILL` or `SIGTERM` - on a thread)</sup>

The [pthreads(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html) library uses low-level stuff (including some [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)-s and [futex(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/futex.7.html)-s etc...; see also [nptl(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/nptl.7.html)) and if you raw-killed (with `tkill` or `tgkill`) some individual thread, your process would be in some wrong state (so [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)) because some internal invariant would be broken.

So study the documentation of your packet receiver program and find some other way. If it is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), study its source code and improve it.

Read more carefully [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html). Signals are meant to be sent to processes (by [kill(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html)) and handled in threads.

And in practice, signals and threads don't marry well. Read some [pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/).

A common trick, when coding a multi-threaded program (and wanting to handle *external* signals like `SIGTERM`) is to use a [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) to your own process and [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) that pipe in some other thread (you might also consider the Linux specific [signalfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html)), with a signal hander [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html)-ing a byte or a few of them into that pipe. That well known trick is well explained in [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/unix-signals.html) (and you could use it in your own program, even without Qt).

Comment: The `tgkill` function provides no way to terminate a thread. It sends a signal to a thread. It is named "kill" because it is the historical way to kill a process and it cannot be used to kill a thread.

Comment: I guess that sending a `SIGKILL` to a thread is harming it. Or is it always killing the entire process? And what about `SIGTERM`? BTW, even  if only a thread is harmed, my point is that the process is in dire state.

Comment: Yes, the `SIGKILL` and `SIGTERM` signals are defined to kill or terminate the process. That is true regardless of what thread receives them -- they still mean the same thing. Terminating a thread without the close cooperation of its process would be a crap shoot and likely catastrophic to the process.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than sending `SIGKILL` you might install a handler for another signal that you know isn't used, and is not blocked/ignored (e.g. `SIGSYS`). In this handler, you could call `syscall(SYS_exit, 0)` - contrary to regular `exit(int)` or `_exit(int)` functions the `exit` syscall terminates only the current thread (LWP) - whole process would be terminated with the `exit_group` syscall.

You might consider calling `pthread_exit(...)` instead of the syscall, but this function is not async-safe, therefore calling it might cause the process to segfault.

All the warnings from other answers about force-terminating threads apply.